# Drupal 7 CCK number

Tags: 7, entities, views

As long as I know there is no number field in Drupal 7. All I can see is a List(integer) field. The problem that I'm facing is in sorting with respect to this field in views. I want my content to be sorted numerically not alphabetically. Suppose I have three nodes with field values of 1,8,13. Sorting with views results in the this order: 1,13,8. Any Solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the content type while creating the field, if you have selected `List(integer)` then it will sort by the numerical value. If you are sure that you have selected `List(integer)` and sill in the view it is not sorting by numeric value, then the culprits can be

1. You have the display Format as a table and table settings has some other default sorting order.
2. Make sure that in the Sort list in the view, your field is above any other fields used for sorting. By default post data field will be used for filtering.
3. If both of the above steps are verified, then may you have rewritten the field, which is affecting the order.

Comment: Choosing number or List(integer) would do the job. I just made a silly mistake ;)